# Cannot force a canvas refresh in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d-games

I am trying to get a game to refresh canvas regularly with a main loop comprising a function to replay a screen and a function to have the computer calculate a move (if it is its turn). The player can select a move 1-9 and then, if the computer has not gone since the player last made a move, it will calculate its move using a very deep tree. The computer move takes several seconds to make its move. Despite having the canvas update before the computer makes a move, it doesn't ever get refreshed until after the computer has gone, meaning both the player and the computer move are shown simultaneously rather than sequentially. What can I do to ensure the canvas is updated every 100 milliseconds and not just after when the computer has calculated its move?

```
function playGame() {
    function doKeyDown(evt) {
        console.log(evt.keyCode)
        if (evt.keyCode > 48 && evt.keyCode < 58) { 
            game.makeMove(evt.keyCode-48); // 1-9 are user actions
        }
    }

    function mainLoop(ctx, game, board) {
        board.showBoard(ctx); // display board
        game.makeMove(0); // zero is computer move
    }

    Canvas.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    let game = new Game();
    let board = new Board(game);
    window.addEventListener( "keydown", doKeyDown, true);
    Canvas.ctx = Canvas.canvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(() => {mainLoop(Canvas.ctx, game, board)}, 100);
};  

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', playGame);
```

Comment: Welcome to the single-threaded nature of JavaScript. When JS is actively running, the browser cannot do *anything* else, and that includes rendering the screen.

Comment: Think about using Web Workers to calculate something in parallel if it's possible for your case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can definitely help you with ensuring your canvas refreshes when you expect.

1. move computationally intensive tasks into Web Workers.
2. utilize `window.requestAnimationFrame()` instead of `setInterval()` for rendering.

**Web Workers**

Web Workers are great for moving computationally intensive tasks into; the MDN documentation for Web Workers states that, "The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface." This will allow the computer's move to be calculated without blocking the rendering thread.

For more information on  Web Workers see: [Web Workers (MDN Web Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

**window.requestAnimationFrame()**

The `window.requestAnimationFrame()` method is the best current method to achieve animations with. Essentially it causes the browser to execute the provided callback just before the next repaint. This is an improvement over the previous `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` methods as it only calls the callback just before the browser repaint, in other words, it reduces unnecessary computations that can be caused by using `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`.

For more information on `window.requestAnimationFrame()` see: [window.requestAnimationFrame() (MDN Web Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

For a nice short article on why to choose `window.requestAnimationFrame()` over `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` see this article by Matt West: [Efficient Animations with requestAnimationFrame](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/efficient-animations-with-requestanimationframe)

**Working Example:**

I have put together a small working example using codesandbox.io; it uses Web Workers and requestAnimationFrame() as I have described. Note that it uses a timer in place of a computationally intensive task, it uses a 5 second timer to simulate a computer move, and a 1 second timer to simulate a player move.

Code Sandbox: [Web Worker & requestAnimationFrame() Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/canvas-webworker-example-pkvvw?file=/src/index.js)